# PC monitor for gentle eyes

Tags: monitors

I was owning Dell 24 inches monitor, which worked for me perfectly for 5 years. Recently I bought new one, exactly the same model. I launched it and my eyes were hurting after only half hour of work (I am working a lot with text, when I watch Youtube or playing games I do not have that issue). I was schocked a bit so I placed those 2 next to each other and... as if it were 2 different monitors (I did tried to calibrate, but it appears that displays are from 2 different leagues). I have discovered that I have exactly the same problem with most of the modern displays that costs ~300-500$. I can only work for half-hour on those. Suprisingly I can work on 27 inch iMac 12 hours straight without single sing of eyes hurt, the same goes with surface 4 pro. Do You know any PC monitor that would behave the same as iMac or Surface Pro ? I am not interested in having 4k or 5k resolution, I am interested in working comfort. Another question - do You know what are so special about those displays (iMac, Macbook display, Surface 4 Pro) ?

Comment: Before we get to recommendations, have you tried things like turning down brightness, changing refresh rates or using a dark background?

Comment: Yes I did, without success unfortunately. Speaking of those 2 DELL's, those were same models. I couldn't get second to look even near as first (brightness, contrast etc.)

Comment: Your question title caught me there.